# How to make line below the input value and decorate this line

Tags: html, css

I need to underline text in `input` that will display value of expression (I'm making a calculator). 
If I use `text-decoration: underline` the line is too thick and too close to the text.[image: after]

I need to make line like this. Line should underline only text, not a whole input.

[image: before]

I use fixed `width: 200px` for input (max value can be five-digit of six-digit). If I don't set `width` input takes 100% of available place. Thus we can't use `border-bottom` because line have `width` like input, but text have line about 70% of input `width`  and we'll get something like this [image].

If it possible, we shouldn't use JavaScript, only CSS.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6b2rmedm/3/#&togetherjs=FH8oeUBrjk)

```css
.calc__total-cost {
  font-size: 56px;
  font-weight: 700;
  width: 200px;
  height: 60px;
  background: transparent;
  color: #efae02;
  text-align: right;
  text-decoration: underline;
  }
```

```html
    <div class="calc__total">
      <input type="text" class="calc__total-cost" id="calc__total-cost-value" value="5000">
      </div>
```

Comment: he actually tried to use a border and text-decoration

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```css
.calc__total-cost{
  border: none;
}
.calc__total-cost:active, .calc__total-cost:focus{
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}
.calc__total{
  position: relative;
}
.calc__total:after{
  position: absolute;
  width: 35px;
  height: 1px;
  background: #333;
  content: '';
  left:0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
    <div class="calc__total">
      <input type="text" class="calc__total-cost" id="calc__total-cost-value" value="5000">
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could play with `height`, `borders` and `outline`: you could partially overlap the underline created with `text-decoration` using a white bottom border. Then you could restore the border using the `outline` property, e.g.

```css
input { 
   width: 300px; 
   height: 4.1rem;
   text-align: right;
   padding: 0 10px;
   text-decoration: underline; 
   font: 5rem Arial; 
   color: gold; 
   border: 0;
   border-top: 10px #fff solid;
   border-bottom: 10px #fff solid;
   outline: 1px #d8d8d8 solid;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="5000"/>
```

As the final result only the number is underlined with a light line (play with bottom border to adjust the tickness)

Comment: How does it work? I removed styles from your code  which I don't need and which don't change anything. All that's left is `height` and  `font`. If I remove them and write `height: 60px`, `font-size: 56px` line is bold. How do they link with each other?  [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rqv3upu8/#&togetherjs=iVpgo3EyjK)